# "Она была такая" или "она была такой"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно: *она была такая* или *она была такой*?

Answer (score 3):

Действительно, возможны оба варианта, **но при этом  интересно найти разные оттенки значений в них.**

В учебниках по стилистике даются рекомендации по употреблению прилагательных в форме И. п. и Т. п. в составных именных  сказуемых. **Указываются два различия: А) И. п. считается более архаичным, а Т. п. более современным; б) И. п. обозначает постоянный признак, а Т. п. - временный признак.** Однако это только тенденции, и в каждом случае следует учитывать дополнительные факторы: время, вид связки и др.

Интересно отметить следующее: Т. п. по своему значению близок к краткой форме прилагательного/причастия, то есть в какой-то мере обозначает процессуальный признак. Поэтому И. п. - это признак **постоянный или просто зафиксированный** в данный момент (**она была такая**), а Т. п. - это признак, отнесенный к **временному отрезку** (**она была такой**).

Сравним два очень похожих предложения и попробуем объяснить авторский выбор в каждом из них:

(1) Она была такая прекрасная, такая тоненькая и прозрачная, что казалась видением, сошедшим со старинной персидской миниатюры.

(2) Она была такой юной и такой нереально красивой, что Ганину вдруг стало страшно.

Кажется, что они могут различаться следующим образом: в первом предложении автор предлагает нам мгновенное впечатление, как бы фотографическое изображение, а во втором - наблюдает за своим предметом  некоторое время с помощью видеокамеры.

Comment: *>> попробуем объяснить авторский выбор в каждом из них

 Кажется, что они могут различаться следующим образом: в первом предложении автор предлагает нам мгновенное впечатление, как бы фотографическое изображение, а во втором - наблюдает за своим предметом некоторое время с помощью видеокамеры*


Притянуто за уши.
Она была такАЯ прекраснАЯ, такая тоненькАЯ и прозрачнАЯ, что кАзАлАсь видением

Попробуйте заменить на "такой прекрасной" и т.д. Фраза сразу перестает играть.

Впрочем, вполне возможно, что и это притянуто за уши

Answer (score 0):

> *она была такая...*
>
> *она была такой...*

Оба варианта правильны.

См. примеры:

[***"она была такая"***](https://www.google.ru/#q=%22%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%B0+%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F%22&newwindow=1&tbm=bks)

[***"она была такой"***](https://www.google.ru/#q=%22%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%B0+%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9%22&newwindow=1&tbm=bks)

Comment: есть ли правило которое это объясняло?

Answer (score 0):

Оба варианта возможны. Есть некоторая разница в смысле, но не очень существенная.

Comment: Подробнее хотелось бы. Хотя в целом - согласен.